# Evaluating $\int^1_0\sqrt{1 - x^2}$

Tags: calculus

How to Evaluate $\int^1_0\sqrt{1 - x^2}$

I know that this is just a $\frac14$ of unit circle, that is $\frac\pi4$, but I want to solve it algebraically.

Comment: Substitute $x=\sin t$.

Comment: But I don't have $\cos t$ in the integrand

Comment: @epsilo, you will have after you substitute $\,dx\,$ by $\,dt\,$...this is why this trick works!

Comment: Yes, you were right. I don't no why, but I thought that I should have the $\cos$ before starting substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the trig substitution $x=\sin\theta$ so that $dx=\cos\theta d\theta$. This leads to:
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta} \cos\theta d\theta= \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\cos^2\theta} \cos\theta d\theta = \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2\theta d\theta
$$
Then make use of the trig identity:
$$
\cos^2\theta = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2}\cos{2\theta}
$$

Comment: $\frac12\cdot\theta + \frac12 \cdot (-\sin 2\theta) \cdot \frac12 = \frac\pi4 - \frac14\cdot 0 = \frac\pi4$ Thanks!